# Why are execv*() arguments inconsistent with execl*()?

Tags: c, exec, standards, argv

Why are the `argv` arguments for the `execv*()` family of functions `char * const []` whereas the `execl*()` family of `arg0...n` args are `const char *`?  Is this just a mistake in the standard, and it should be `const char * const []` or is there a reason for the strings to be non-const in the array case but const in the explicitly passed arguments case?

```
   int execl(const char *path, const char *arg0, ... /*, (char *)0 */);
   int execv(const char *path, char *const argv[]);
   int execle(const char *path, const char *arg0, ... /*,
          (char *)0, char *const envp[]*/);
   int execve(const char *path, char *const argv[], char *const envp[]);
   int execlp(const char *file, const char *arg0, ... /*, (char *)0 */);
   int execvp(const char *file, char *const argv[]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find an authoritative answer, but I suspect the two call signatures differ based on how they are created and how they are used.

In the case of `execl*()`, it's entirely possible your function was passed a `const char*` which you are passing on. If the signature of `execl*()` was not `const char*`, then you would get compiler warnings.

In the case of `execv*()`, since it's an array that was likely built by you, maintain constantness of the string value is not as important.  BUT what is important is that the `execv*()` not manipulate the pointers -- otherwise it's possible the last element could be modified so it no longer correctly point to NULL -- which is required.

Perhaps someone with closer familiarity of the spec to clarify where I may have gone wrong.